# How to print a range of values from an array?

Tags: java

I have an array of ints sorted in ascending order. I want to be able to call my method and return the x to x+yth highest valued elements in that order. I can't seem to wrap my head around how the logic should look for the for(init;condition;incr/decr) part however.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class test{
    public static void printRangeOfInts(int x, int y) {
        int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
        for(int i = y-1; i >= x; --i){
            System.out.println("Value:" + a[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("printRangeOfInts(2,3) should print:\nValue: 6\nValue: 5");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Prints wrong:");
        printRangeOfInts(2,3);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("printRangeOfInts(1,7)should print:\nValue: 7\nValue: 6\nValue: 5\nValue: 4\nValue: 3\nValue: 2\nValue: 1");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Prints wrong:");
        printRangeOfInts(1,7);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why printRangeOfInts(2,3) should print: Value: 6\nValue: 5

Comment: @Saurav Kumar Because the value 6 and 5 are the 2nd and 3rd most highest valued elements in the array.

Comment: Ok, make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be correct:

```
public static void printRangeOfInts(int x, int y) {
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    for (int i = a.length - x; i >= a.length - y; i--) {
            System.out.println("Value:" + a[i]);
    }
}
```